# Serialize static ArrayList objects

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I'm building this Client/Server application in **text mode** using RMI.
In this app, i need to use TWO ArrayLists and then save them to TWO files in the Server side.

Thing is, i have to operate these ArrayLists in remote methods (NOT pass them as arguments), so, i have to declare them and instantiate them in the class as **global variables**.

Problem is, when im preparing the code in **main()** to initially load the Objects from the files to the ArrayLists and then, just before Server terminates, save the ArrayLists to the files ,,, i'm forced to declare the ArrayLists as **static** because i'm using them inside **main()**, which is a static environment (public static void main(String[] args))! So serialization won't work, because they are static!

Here's a piece of code from Server side where i have the global variables, constructor and just TWO methods as an example:

```
public class Server extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements ServerInterface{
private static ArrayList<UC> cadeiras = new ArrayList<UC>();
private static ArrayList<Utilizador> utilizadores = new ArrayList<Utilizador>();
private static ClientInterface client;
private static int numAcessos = 0;
private Exercicio exercicio;

protected Server(int port) throws RemoteException{
    super(port, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(null, null, true));      
}

public boolean verificaUtilizador(String login, String password) throws RemoteException{
    for(int i = 0; i < utilizadores.size(); i++)
        if(utilizadores.get(i).getNome().equals(login))
            if(utilizadores.get(i).getSenha().equals(password)){
                numAcessos++;
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}

public boolean verificaCodigoUC(int codigo)throws RemoteException{
    for(int i = 0; i < cadeiras.size(); i++)
        if(cadeiras.get(i).getCodigo() == codigo)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Now the part from **main()** where i load/save the ArrayLists to the files:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    File ficheiroUCs = new File("cadeiras.dat");
    File ficheiroUsers = new File("utilizadores.dat");
    try{
        FileInputStream isUCs = new FileInputStream(ficheiroUCs);
        ObjectInputStream oISUCs = new ObjectInputStream(isUCs);
        FileInputStream isUsers = new FileInputStream(ficheiroUsers);
        ObjectInputStream oISUsers = new ObjectInputStream(isUsers);
        cadeiras = (ArrayList<UC>)oISUCs.readObject();
        utilizadores = (ArrayList<Utilizador>)oISUsers.readObject();
        oISUCs.close();
        oISUsers.close();
        isUCs.close();
        isUsers.close();
    } catch( IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    try{
        setSettings();
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(null, null, true));
        System.out.println("RMI registry ready.");
        Server servidor = new Server(1099);
        registry.bind("//" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + "/Portal", servidor);
        System.out.println("Portal do Saber bound in registry");
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print("Exception starting RMI registry: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        FileOutputStream osUCs = new FileOutputStream(ficheiroUCs);
        ObjectOutputStream oOSUCs = new ObjectOutputStream(osUCs);
        FileOutputStream osUsers = new FileOutputStream(ficheiroUsers);
        ObjectOutputStream oOSUsers = new ObjectOutputStream(osUsers);
        oOSUCs.writeObject(cadeiras);
        oOSUsers.writeObject(utilizadores);
        oOSUCs.close();
        oOSUsers.close();
        osUCs.close();
        osUsers.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I already tried to instantiate all the Objects (ArrayLists and Files) in the constructor and then create TWO local methods: One to load the files to the ArrayLists and another one to save the data to the files. But then i have to call these methods from inside the main()! So the result is the same!

I know if i have used Java Swing or FX instead of text mode, probably, i would have not found this kind of constraint ... But, on the other hand, there must be a solution for this? Right?

I really need some guidance here because i'm really stuck!

Many, many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no actual RMI content to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken.

You are serializing the objects themselves, not an object or class in which they are contained as members, so the fact that they are static in that class is completely irrelevant.

You don't have a problem to solve.

Comment: So how come i can't get the data to be saved into the files?! I must be doing something wrong! Maybe because i don't know exactly what should happen (which conditions to have just before Server terminates) to know exactly where to put the code to save the ArrayLists and close all the OutputStreams! EJP: Many, many thanks for the enlightenment. Now i know for sure it's not because of the static environment.

Comment: I'm sorry but concerning to Java, i have a LOT to learn! I forgot to mention that the ArrayList called "cadeiras" contains objects from another class called "UC", and this one has inside of it another ArrayList with Objects from another class called "Exercicio" and so on .... All of these classes are Serializable. Is this what you're referring?! Pardon for my ignorance!

Comment: I don't know why you can't 'get the data to be saved into the files', because you haven't provided any *symptoms.* Only your incorrect guesswork. As a matter of fact you hadn't even stated that it didn't work, only that you thought it wouldn't. If you're getting an exception you need to post it, in your question.